# One R#5 license for VS 2008 & 2010? (only one at a time)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, licensing, resharper-5.0

R#5 supports VS2008 and VS2010?

Can I use it in both IDEs on my one workstation with only one license?  I won't run the two IDEs at the same time.

Comment: Fair question.  SO has a way of providing more information about a question than you would have thought to ask for (the links in the answers below are good examples).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the license, most the [personal license](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/buy.jsp#personal_licenseTerms) is per user, the [commercial license](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/buy.jsp#commercial_licenseTerms) is per concurrent developer

Answer (score 1):

[JetBrains has a licensing chart](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/license-matrix.jsp) - I personally read the chart as meaning a license is for the person.  That person can run it on whatever computers/environments they want, as long as they are the only one using it.  Commercial license works the same, but it's a number of people instead of one person.